# getUser returns 0 even, when user accepted application and is logged in (aka infinity loop)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Here is a simple code, it runs on a single site and is as simple as it can be:

```
@ini_set('display_errors','On'); // enable or disable public display of errors (use 'On' or 'Off')
include_once('lib/facebook.php');

// Create our application instance
$config = array(
  'appId' => 'xx',
  'secret' => 'yyy'
);
$link = 'http://someurl.com';
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){ ?>
    <p>logged in</p>
<?php } else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'         => 'manage_pages,email',
    'redirect_uri'  => $link,
    ));
    echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login with FB</a>'; 
}
```

So what id does, it showes link to login when user is not logged in (or to be specific - if getUser() doesnt recive anything), and paragraph with text if getUser gives what it should give (usually users prefer to put redirect there, if getUser returns 0, which gets to infinity loop described belove)

Simple test will show a problem. Accessing it by site url, even when user permission is given, shows login url instead of paragraph.

Where is the problem? 
While trying to figure it out, I have added site's url as "App on Facebook", so it can be accessed from inside of facebook. And eureka, if it is accessed this way (by Canvas Page url), getUser() works correctly. Whats even more, when once You have visited through Canvas Page url link, then  when visiting site directly - getUser() also works correctly.

So where is the catch?
Trying with browser's incognito function i have figured otu, that there is something stored on user browser. Visiting site directly from a browser, where user already have been on Canvas Page url shows correct responce, while when on a browser where user havent visited Canvas Page url, shows login url.

So it seams, that the problem is somehow connected with browser cache, and facebook doesnt set it correct way when visiting throught page instead of Canvas Page itself.

Also, when acces to app is given, when user clicks on login link, he is automatically redirected back to oryginal page with state and code as _GET parameters, so when in code one puts auto redirect -  infinity loop with diffrent state and code value in link everytime redirect fires happends.

Anybody have an idea how to correct this issue working only with php sdk?

Comment: I hit the same problem a while ago. The reason was due to the redirect urls not being identical for both of the 2 stage auth. That's where I'd suggest you start. And don't assume that because it's in the same variable that it'll do it right :P

Comment: Jon - what do You mean "2 stage auth"? Do you mean diffrence between lind variable in php and link provided in facebook app settings?